# Filter Measures for a particular year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I´m new to DAX and have a question regarding filtering measures. As you can see in the attachment, I want to filter both measures, `volume CY` (current year) and `volume LY` only for year 2018.

```
        Volume LY   Volume CY
2016    65.024.635
2017    65.024.635  63.602.450
2018    63.602.450  21.597.407
```

I want to link the filtering with an indicator (`Counter`). This counter has values in range [0-3]. Each year has semesters, for example Current Year has semester 0 and 1, 2017 - 2 and 3, 2016 - 4 and 5. In this case, I want to select 1 for the counter and it should filter `semester <= 1` for the year 2018:

```
        Volume LY   Volume CY
2018    63.602.450  21.597.407
```

But if I filter measure `volume CY` with:

```
FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table);Table[Semester]<=MAX('Table2'[Counter]));
```

then measure `Volume LY` automatically gets filtered for `semester <= 1` and it won´t show values for LY. My questions is: How can i use filter function to get values for both measures for current year?

Measure Volume Current Year:

```
Volume_CY:=CALCULATE(
[Volume];
'Scenario'[Scenario1]=1;
FILTER(Table;Table[Semester]<=MAX('Table2'[Counter])))
```

Measure Volume LY:

```
  Volume LY:= CALCULATE(
    [Volume_CY];
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table);Table[Semester]<=MAX('Table2'[Counter]));
    FILTER(ALL(Table[Year]))
```

Here is the result of this two measures with counter 1 and scenario 1: As you can see it doesn´t show the LY Value which should be 63.602.450.

```
Scenario    1
Counter 1   

        Volume LY   Volume CY
2018               21.597.407
Total              21.597.407
```

Now i have a result like this:

```
        Volume CY    Volume LY
20151   77.222.12   77.222.12 
20152   88.868.719  88.868.719
20161   87.987.22   87.987.22
20162   92.906.793  92.906.793
20171   101.102.12  101.102.12
20172   105.029.725 105.029.725
```

And this is what i´m expecting:

```
        Volume CY    Volume LY
20151   77.222.12
20152   88.868.719  49.123.12
20161   87.987.22   77.222.12
20162   92.906.793  88.868.719
20171   101.102.12  87.987.22
20172   105.029.725 92.906.793
```

Comment: Can you share your table relationship schema please?

Comment: Hi there is no relationship between Table and Table2

Comment: How about a small example we could copy to reproduce?

Comment: I´ve edited my question above. please have a look

Comment: How about this? `Volume_LY:=CALCULATE(
[Volume];
'Scenario'[Scenario1]=1;
FILTER(Table;Table[Semester]<=MAX('Table2'[Counter])-2))`

Comment: the problem is that i have to use Volume_CY to calculate measure Volume_LY. And if do so and filter counter = 1 measure volume is getting filtered already for 2018. And if i use the same filtering for volume ly, which is based on Volume, the values are empty. So i´m wondering if there is a another way of filtering for both measures.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one thing, what I meant to send is `Volume_LY:=CALCULATE( [Volume]; 'Scenario'[Scenario1]=1; FILTER(ALL(Table);Table[Semester]<=MAX('Table2'[Counter])-2))`

Comment: the measure "Volume" used in your function is filtered to FILTER(Table;Table[Semester]<=MAX('Table2'[Counter]))). How can i remove this filter in the measure Volume_LY?

Comment: `Calculate( [Volume]; ALL('Table') )` will calculate `Volume` ignoring any filters/selections.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Given following source data:

```
year,   Volume CY
20151,  77222.12
20152,  88868.719
20161,  87987.22
20162,  92906.793
20171,  101102.12
20172,  105029.725
```

Expected result could be achieved with a following calculated column:

```
Volume LY = CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Volume CY]),
  ALL(Table1),
  Table[year] = EARLIER(Table[year])-10)
```

Which results in:

```
year,   Volume CY,  Volume LY
20151,  77222.12,
20152,  88868.719,
20161,  87987.22,   77222.12
20162,  92906.793,  88868.719
20171,  101102.12,  87987.22
20172,  105029.725, 92906.793
```

Which respects filters on "`year`" column.

---

(Old answer below)

Rolling sum:

```
year    semester    volume
2016    1           123
2017    3           1345
2018    5           3465
2016    2           3465
2017    4           3465
2018    6           634
```

Calculated columns:

```
VCY = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[volume]),
  ALL(Table1),
  Table1[semester] <= EARLIER(Table1[semester]))

VLY = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[volume]),
  ALL(Table1),
  Table1[semester] <= EARLIER(Table1[semester]) - 2)
```

Results in:

```
year, semester, volume, VCY,   VLY
2016, 1,        123,    123,
2016, 2,        3465,   3588,
2017, 3,        1345,   4933,  123
2017, 4,        3465,   8398,  3588
2018, 5,        3465,   11863, 4933
2018, 6,        634,    12497, 8398
```

Rolling sum on yearly basis:

```
VCY = 
VAR RowYear = Table1[year]
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[volume]),
  ALL(Table1),
  table1[year] = RowYear,
  Table1[semester] <= EARLIER(Table1[semester]))

VLY = 
VAR RowYear = Table1[year]-1
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[volume]),
  ALL(Table1),
  table1[year] = RowYear,
  Table1[semester] <= EARLIER(Table1[semester])-2)
```

Results in:

```
year, semester, volume, VCY,  VLY
2016, 1,        123,    123,
2016, 2,        3465,   3588,
2017, 3,        1345,   1345, 123
2017, 4,        3465,   4810, 3588
2018, 5,        3465,   3465, 1345
2018, 6,        634,    4099, 4810
```

Comment: Hi i´ve edited my question above. Please have a look. Now i want to have LY values on semester basis.

Comment: You should show your data and expected result (doesn't have to be real data, just enough for an example)

Comment: Hi the data is in my question above. It´s similar to yours. Instead of year i now have for example 20162 for second half of year 2016. I can´t go back with -1 year. The LY volume should refer to the half years. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the result:

```
        Volume CY    Volume LY
20151   77.222.12   77.222.12 
20152   88.868.719  88.868.719
20161   87.987.22   87.987.22
20162   92.906.793  92.906.793
20171   101.102.12  101.102.12
20172   105.029.725 105.029.725
```

And this is what i´m expecting:

```
        Volume CY    Volume LY
20151   77.222.12
20152   88.868.719  49.123.12
20161   87.987.22   77.222.12
20162   92.906.793  88.868.719
20171   101.102.12  87.987.22
20172   105.029.725 92.906.793
```

And if i filter on one specific year/half year e.g. 20162 it should show following:

```
           Volume CY    Volume LY
   20162   92.906.793  88.868.719
```

This is what i´m getting with: `FILTER(ALL(Table);Table(Year)=MAX(Table(Year)-10)) --> **The grand total for Volume CY is missing!**

```
                    Volume CY   Volume LY
              20152 88.868.719  49.123.12
              20162 92.906.793  88.868.719
              20172 105.029.725 92.906.793
Grand Total                     186.687.824
```

Comment: Your example has 20152 then 20162; is there no 20161?

Comment: Please have a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes there is also first half data. This was filtered for second half.

Comment: Hi thank you for the edit. Since it´s a measure i have to filter it with following: FILTER(ALL(Table[year] = MAX(Table[year])-10). But when i use  this i´m missing the grand total for Volume LY. I will edit my question above with an example

Comment: Why does `Volume CY` have to be a measure? It looks like it's more suitable to be a calculated column. Please post your original data not measures you added.